# PHP - post data ends when '&' is in data

Tags: php, http-post

I'm posting data using jquery/ajax and PHP at the backend. Problem being, when I input something like 'Jack & Jill went up the hill' I'm only receiving 'Jack' when it gets to the backend.

I have thrown an error at the frontend before that data is sent which alerts 'Jack & Jill went up the hill'.

When I put `die(print_r($_POST));` at the very top of my index page I'm only getting `[key] => Jack`

How can I be losing the data?

I thought It may have been my filter;

```
<?php

function filter( $data ) {
    $data = trim( htmlentities( strip_tags( mb_convert_encoding( $data, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8") ) ) ); 
    if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) { 
        $data = stripslashes( $data ); 
    } 
    //$data = mysql_real_escape_string( $data ); 
    return $data;
}

echo "<xmp>" . filter("you & me") . "</xmp>";

?>
```

but that returns fine in the test above `you & me` which is in place after I added `die(print_r($_POST));`.

Can anyone think of how and why this is happening?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely failing to URL encode the data. The `&` character separates key-value pairs in submitted form data.

Use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURIComponent) for this

Comment: Thank you both, still learning javascript/jquery, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

POST data is sent via the HTTP header in form that is just like the GET data in the url. For example, the data could look like `var1=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3`. As you can imagine, if the data contains ampersands itself, it's not going to work too well on that format.  To be precise, the problem is in how you are submitting the data.

To use ampersands in the post data (or in urls, for that matter) they must be "urlencoded", which means that you must use `%26` for the `&` character. So, it's not really your PHP that has the problem, but whatever is sending the data. It's not encoding the values properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use either encode() or escape() at the javascript end

Comment: escape() is the right function to url escape special characters

Comment: No, it isn't. It doesn't work properly for non-ASCII characters and has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

In the Javascript end you should use `escape()`.

In the PHP end the function is named `urlencode()`.